# Axios @ React : Error: Request failed with status code 400 for PATCH

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, patch

i got this error when trying to Patch with axios on React.
The back-end is working [Node - Mongo] and everything is fine when trying in Postman.

Here is my code :
[back-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S7mS.png)
[front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4EPQ.png)

Any help plz ?

Comment: What are the properties inside the `selectedUser` data in the fron-end?

Comment: Those are the property inside selected User : 
id: null,
 name: "",
 email: "",
 password: "",

Answer (score 0):

Your request fails because the `allowedUpdates` does not contain the `id` property that should send with the `1selectedUser`

Comment: Indeed it was that. Thanks a lot ! It fixed my problem.

Comment: No problem! :) :)